# Protect folders in CakePHP2

Tags: cakephp

Please, does someone knows how to protect my folders in CakePhp from direct acess? I mean, I don't wanna malicious users type someting like `http://localhost/MySite/CSS/` and see all my CSS files. Also, i don't wanna someome see JS, IMG, LAYOUTS and nothing else!!!

I mean.. i wanna show something like an error message if user try to acess my folders know? Like any other sites does. I tried someting with HTACESS but not working properly. **I wanna protect all folders from direct acess!!**

Remember, i'm using CAKEPHP+2

Thank you guys.

Comment: you don't want people to see your CSS/IMG? I don't see any reason for that, people can always get any css or images using the network tab. Now, a total different thing is restrict the listing of files in a directory, if you are working with apache then you can simply put a .htaccess file.

Comment: Microsfot exemple 'http://c.s-microsoft.com/en-us/CMSStyles/style.csx?k=cfd79f249' but when you try to acess 'http://c.s-microsoft.com/en-us/CMSStyles/' you got redirected to error page, because they protected their folders know? Thats what i wanna do. I think is not professional way allow people to see your folders contents know? Thats it.

Comment: Like apple 'http://images.apple.com/global/styles/base.css' and if you try to acess 'http://images.apple.com/global/' or 'http://images.apple.com/global/styles/' you got redirected to error page.

Comment: Ok. How to do what you told me?

Comment: Your layouts shouldn’t be web-accessible (your document root should be set to **app/webroot/**. As for CSS, images, JavaScript files etc. If you mean you don’t want directory contents listed then make sure `Options -Indexes` is set at the top of your **.htaccess** file, but CakePHP denies access to those directories any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CakePHP does this automatically.  If you try to access www.yoursite.com/css, it will try to access the "CssController", which doesn't exists, so it will throw an error - it won't show your folder contents.  The same goes for the rest.

Comment: I'm in localhost and i'm acessing all files from one folder. At my server hosting, this acess will auto be removed?

Comment: You shouldn't be able to from local or server.  Maybe a mod_rewrite issue or something similar?